# How can I write in a equation "~" with more aesthetics?

Tags: equations, tilde

I know that `\tilde{a}` in a equation shows:

[image]

but when I write `\tilde{V^{\mu}},\tilde{V}^{\mu}` in a equation, it shows:

[image]

and I am searching something like that:

[image]

They are similar, but they are not the same. How can I write this ***V*** ?

Comment: Perhaps `\widetilde`? `\widetilde{V}^{\mu}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\widetilde` from `yhmath` is better than the default, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,yhmath }

\begin{document}

     \[ \widetilde{V}\quad \widetilde{V}^\mu \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]